# When does Linq-to-SQL run the query?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Can you tell me where Linq2SQL executes the query against my sql server? I'm hoping it happens after I map to my domain object called `Car`.

```
public class Car
{
    public Guid CarId { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int HorsePower { get; set; }
}

public class CarRepository
{
    private readonly MyDataContext _dc;

    private readonly Func<DbCar, Car> _mappedCar =
        c => new Car
                 {
                     CarId = c.CarId,
                     HorsePower = c.HorsePower,
                     Make = c.Make,
                     Model = c.Model,
                 };

    public CarRepository(MyDataContext dc)
    {
        _dc = dc;
    }

    public Car GetCar(Guid carId)
    {
        var car = _dc.GetTable<DbCar>()
            .Select(_mappedCar)
            .Single(c => c.CarId == carId);                

        return car;
    }        
}
```

Comment: Does that actually work? If so, I am quite impressed Linq-to-SQL can resolve your ``_mappedCar`` function and map that ``c => c.CarId == carId`` predicate back into the db world...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's correct.  Execution of the SQL query is deferred until `Single()` is called.
You can confirm this by breaking the query down like this and adding a breakpoint:

```
var carQuery = _dc.GetTable<DbCar>().Select(_mappedCar)  // <= breakpoint
var car = carQuery.Single(c => c.CarId == carId);
```

If you run a [profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx) against your database, you should see where the query is executed as you step through the code.

More info here: [LINQ and Deferred Execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx)

Comment: Just be careful when using Single() as it will iterate through the entire collection even if the element has been found. It could potentially impact performance. If you are certain there is only one element, use First() or FirstOrDefault().

Comment: @Vince - The query would only return a single record.

Comment: @Phill: Yes but Single() will make sure there is no other element matching that criteria and therefore, scan the entire collection. It could impact performance if you have "lots" of items.

Comment: @Vince - There is no performance impact, there is no collection with multiple records. This isn't an in-memory collection, it's creating a SQL query which will return a single result set with a single record.

Comment: I suggest you execute your LINQ statement and check the generated SQL. The Single() method will execute SELECT, First() will execute SELECT TOP (1)

Comment: @Vince - Just ran two queries looking for a record in the middle of a table with more than a billion rows. 1 with top 1, and 1 without. No difference in execution time since it's a index seek.

Comment: So it's OK to go through a billion rows even when there is no need to?  What if the field isn't indexed? I'll point you here instead. http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/04/14/c.net-little-wonders-first-and-single---similar-yet-different.aspx

Comment: @Vince - The OP is selecting by the identity column, selecting top 1 isn't going to improve performance, you're only going to get a performance benefit if the column isn't indexed or you're selecting by columns other than the identity. If there is no index on the identity then there is obviously bigger issues to worry about.

Comment: @Vince: Linq to SQL has all sorts of different strategies than Linq to Objects.